# How to embed WP in static html <iframe> without JS or Ajax or JSQ?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, iframe

How can I embed my company's live public webpage to my company's intranet site I am redesigning now, as I click a link in intranet? I am using iframe. The company public domain is in WordPress. 
I came across these links, but none could help me:
- [How do you put only a certain section of a website into an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14117763/how-do-you-put-only-a-certain-section-of-a-website-into-an-iframe)
- [Loading wordpress page content in colorbox Iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17276443/loading-wordpress-page-content-in-colorbox-iframe?rq=1)

My HTML

```
<div class="menuItem">
<a href="http://mvrcancerhospital.com/camps/" target="displayBox">    <b>Events</b></a>
</div><br><br>
<div class="menuItem">
<a href="http://mvrcancerhospital.com/news/" target="displayBox">     <b>News</b></a>
</div><br><br>
<iframe src="" frameborder="0" name="displayBox" width="100%" height="400px">   </iframe>
```

My CSS

```
.menuItem
{
float: left; 
margin-top: 5%;
width: 120px;

font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:15px;
font-weight:bolder;

transition-property: width;
}

.menuItem:hover
{
color: #CB4154;
transform: scale(1.2);
}

.leftSec .menuItem
{
font-size:18px;
}
```

Comment: Would the site load speed of the webpage, I am opening in iframe effect the condition, to just not open the link in my iframe. Because, as I checked the page insight tool, the response was below average.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option in Wordpress to disable frame or iframe displaying your website content under the **WP Security -> Miscellaneous -> Frames Tab**.
In which you get an option to Enable iFrame Protection.
If the checkbox is clicked you won't be able to display the content directly to your iFrame. If unchecked the other site's iFrame would be able to display your webpage. 
:)